# Django SelectDateWidget inline select (bootstrap?)

Tags: html, css, django

I'm using SelectDateWidget in a form in django for a birthday field. It display three selects for day, month and year.

The problem is they don't display inline, but stacked vertically.

I'm using a tag for each field, in this case

```
{{ form.birthdate }}
```

How do I display them inline?

Thanks in advace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved it adding a new class on the widget **snps-inline-select** with the code:

```css
.snps-inline-select {
    width: auto;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

The widget code is this

```py
'birthdate': SelectDateWidget(attrs = {
            'placeholder': 'Ingrese fecha de nacimiento',
            'data-date-format': 'dd/mm/yyyy',
            # added the class snps-inline-select
            'class': 'form-control snps-inline-select'
        }),
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Bootstrap 5 you can use utility classes directly:

```py
SelectDateWidget(
    attrs={
        'class': 'form-select w-auto d-inline-block',
    }
)
```